# Mail sent from Dev environment, but not Test environment - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail

I have an application that allows users to request registration for an event. When an invite request is submitted, the controller executes this piece of code:

```
EventMailer.notify_admins(@user, subject, topic).deliver
```

The app was working fine (development, test and production), but a couple of weeks ago, invite requests filled through the test and production environments stopped sending the email to admins. It's still working fine from the development environment. When I check the test environment log file, I see the following in it:

```
Rendered event_mailer/notify_admins.html.erb (1.3ms)        
Rendered event_mailer/notify_admins.text.erb (1.0ms)        

Sent mail to xxxx@xxxxx.com (1529ms)        
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 20:45:00 +0000        
From: xxxx@xxxxxxx.com        
To: xxxx@xxxxx.com        
Message-ID: <5131134cdd3aa_3cf96d18707060@xxxx-test.mail>        
Subject: Invite request received from: John Doe        
Mime-Version: 1.0        
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;        
boundary="--==_mimepart_5131134cc6832_3cf96d1870674a";        
charset=UTF-8        
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit        



----==_mimepart_5131134cc6832_3cf96d1870674a        
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 20:45:00 +0000        
Mime-Version: 1.0        
Content-Type: text/plain;        
 charset=UTF-8        
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit        
Content-ID: <5131134cd7f78_3cf96d18706818@xxxx-test.mail>        

Invite request received from:         

First Name: John        
Last Name: Doe        
Email Address: john_doe@xxxx.com        

http://test.xxxxx.com/users/109/edit        



----==_mimepart_5131134cc6832_3cf96d1870674a        
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2 013 20:45:00 +0000        
Mime-Version: 1.0        
Content-Type: text/html;        
 charset=UTF-8        
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit        
Content-ID: <5131134cdb33d_3cf96d187069bd@dent-test.mail>        

<p>Invite request received from: </p>        

<p>First Name: John </p>        
<p>Last Name: Doe </p>        
<p>Email Address: john_doe@xxxxx.com </p>        

http://test.xxxx.com/users/109/edit        

<a href=""> Click here to manage request </a>        


----==_mimepart_5131134cc6832_3cf96d1870674a--        

Redirected to http://test.xxxxx.com/        
Completed 302 Found in 3343ms (ActiveRecord: 99.8ms)
```

...But the email is not received and when I look at the mail logs (sent emails, Google mail), I don't see anything in the sent folder (though it's sent fine when I am on the development environment)

I am using Google apps as my mail server and the code on development/test/production is EXACTLY the same. To make sure there are no cached resources, I also pre-compiled assets on both test and production and restarted the Apache server. Any ideas?

## environments

The test, dev and production environments smtp settings sections are the same:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: "xxxxxxx.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["MY_EMAIL_FROM"],
    password: ENV["MY_EMAIL_FROM_PWD"]
```

}

When I set the config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors to TRUE on TEST and PRODUCTION, I get a 500 error. If it's set to false, then the email simply won't be sent.

Comment: Do the mail messages show up in the sent mail folder on the google app account?

Comment: In my post I mentioned that when I looked in the mail logs (sent email on Google), I don't see anything in the Sent folder, but I do see the sent email when I'm using the development environment

Comment: Missed that you said you looked in the sent emails on the google mail.  What does your `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` look like is it sending to the google smtp server directly for all environments?

Comment: See the edits to my question

Comment: I would suspect `user_name: ENV["MY_EMAIL_FROM"],
    password: ENV["MY_EMAIL_FROM_PWD"]` are not available in the environment.  You could add a `logger.info("#{ENV["MY_EMAIL_FROM_PWD"]} #{ENV["MY_EMAIL_FROM"]}")` to see

Comment: You hunch was right. It's odd because this has been working fine (for at least the past 8 months), and when I log in the server as test or production and do env, I can see the environment variables fine. The only big change is that I started using Rails gem v 3.2.6 as opposed to 3.2.3, could it be that this gem has an issue reading environment variables? The env is one of the first things I checked for. If you see my original post, you'll see that the user_name (from) is picked up correctly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25400/discussion-between-hwatkins-and-eastsidedeveloper)